# Ubuntu 22.04 only boots in lowlatency kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, 22.04, zoom-meeting

I think it is linked to NVIDIA drivers but I am not sure. I had nvidia drivers installed(not sure which one) and everything was working correctly. Since I started using zoom my system started rebooting randomly. After persistent reboots, Ubuntu decided to not use nvidia anymore which I am suspecting now may have been corrupted driver.

- I installed the driver again and after reboot got blank screen even on grub.
- Used live boot cd to fix the grub

Now I am able to start Ubuntu only in low latency kernels, generic and regulars do not work

Any help will be appreciated on this:

Nvidia Card - GTX 1660 ti mobile
Kernel: 6.2.0-1009 but only 6.2.0-1009-lowlatency works